# Windows 10 Metro apps crash on startup or are greyed out

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

A bit of background info: I have installed Windows 10 about 5 times.

The first 4 it would only work until the first reboot because during the setup phase it would automatically install a faulty driver and on the first available restart it would break. However all metro apps worked fine before the first reboot.

The 5th time I switched my internet off and window 10 setup finished without internet. That means the faulty driver didn't automatically get installed so I had a chance to switch off the automatic driver installation. However it also meant Windows 10 didn't get activated during the setup phase. I switched internet on, activated Windows 10. Now my computer works fine but all Metro apps are greyed out and not working. For some of them the application crashes and others give me the error "This app can't open"

I tried all obvious solutions

1. `sfc /scannow` and the DISM command
2. Reinstalling them using: `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`
3. Reinstalling them using reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1 script
4. Starting the Application Identity and App Readiness Services

and a couple of other random suggestions I saw online.
For me nothing has worked.

I tried digging deeper and looking at the event logs the error message when trying to open the store is:

```
    Activation of application Microsoft.Getstarted_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: 
The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem. 
See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

Looking at the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log:

```
    Activation of the app Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App 
for the Windows.Launch contract was blocked with error 0x80073CFC 
because its package is in state: 66.
```

So I suspect my apps where working fine before because Windows activated during the setup phase and now there is a problem because Windows activated after the setup phase so the Metro apps are stuck in some sort of non activated limbo.

Any ideas?

Comment: the error means ERROR_NEEDS_REMEDIATION (The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem.). Try to reinstall them via Powershell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt185364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Reinstalling using this guide didn't solve the problem. Is there a more advanced way to reinstall?

Comment: not really. Repair Windows by doing an inplace upgrade if nothing helps: https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/#Repair_Installing_Windows_10

Comment: Can't do that cause it downloads the faulty driver that DESTROYS my computer. I had to spend a week to suppress it from doing just that just to get the laptop running.

Comment: I have no other ideas.

Comment: you can also try the app troubleshooter: http://aka.ms/diag_apps10

Comment: The troubleshooter fails to identify the problem :(

Comment: here I'm out of ideas. ask this the Microsoft support.